# SQL Server full text search and spaces

Tags: sql, sql-server, search, text

I have a column with a product names. Some names look like ‘ab-cd’ ‘ab cd’
Is it possible to use full text search to get these names when user types ‘abc’ (without spaces) ? The `like` operator is working for me, but I’d like to know if it’s possible to use full text search.

Comment: Full Text Search is *language* oriented. It works in terms of *words* and *phrases*. You shouldn't expect it to work with spaces or punctuation that it's already using to *separate* out the words.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use FTS to find terms that are adjacent to each other, like words separated by a space you should use a proximity term.

You can define a proximity term by using the `NEAR` keyword or the `~` operator in the search expression, [as documented here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx).

So if you want to find `ab` followed immediately by `cd` you could use the expression,

```
'NEAR((ab,cd), 0)'
```

searching for the word `ab` followed by the word `cd` with 0 terms in-between.

Comment: But if user put 'abc' in a search string how would I now that 'NEAR((ab,cd), 0)' sould be created ?

Comment: @serg88, presumably you'd have to parse the text and search for, `'abc|a-bc|ab-c|a-b-c|NEAR((a, bc), 0)|NEAR((ab, c), 0)|NEAR((a, b, c), 0)'`, as the length of the string continues you can see the complexity would grow exponentially.

Answer (score 2):

No, unfortunately you cannot make such search via full-text. You can only use `LIKE` in that case `LIKE ('ab%c%')`

**EDIT1:**

You can create a view (`WITH SCHEMABINDING`!) with some `id` and column name in which you want to search:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.ftview WITH SCHEMABINDING 
AS
SELECT  id,
        REPLACE(columnname,' ','') as search_string
FROM YourTable
```

Then create index

```
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX UCI_ftview ON dbo.ftview (id ASC)
```

Then create full-text search index on `search_string` field.

After that you can run `CONTAINS` query with `"abc*"` search and it will find what you need.

**EDIT2:**

But it wont help if `search_string` does not start with your search term.

For example:

*ab c d -> abcd* and you search `cd`

Comment: I don't understand your comment. OP wrote: *Is it possible to use full text search to get these names when user types ‘abc’ (without spaces)* so whats about 'not using FTS'. Please, clarify.

Comment: apologies, didn't read your answer. However, I'm don't think concatenating all words into one super term is a sensible solution. What will you do if the super term does not start with your first search term.

Comment: You are right, that's an issue here. Thanks, I should add this info to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

No. Full Text Search is based on WORDS and Phrases. It does not store the original text. In fact, depending on configuration it will not even store all words - there are so called stop words that never go into the index. Example: in english the word "in" is not selective enough to be considered worth storing.

> Some names look like ‘ab-cd’ ‘ab cd’

Those likely do not get stored at all. At least the 2nd example is actually 2 extremely short words - quite likely they get totally ignored.

So, no - full text search is not suitable for this.

Comment: actually, `ab` and `cd` are not words in the default stop list so wouldn't be ignored but you are right that you would have a problem searching for actual stop/noise words.

Comment: I am not sure that there is not also a minimum word length - so ab and cd may simply be ignored because of that.

Comment: ‘ab-cd’ ‘ab cd’ - it wasn't a real data, just an example. And thanks for the answer - 'full text search is not suitable for this' - this is what I wanted to know

Comment: @TomTom, I am sure and there isn't a minimum word length.